# Localize watchkit companion app display name

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I am having some issues localizing app display name on apple watch companion app. Following the guide lines i have localize the CFBundleName as follow:

CFBundleDisplayName = "My app";
CFBundleName = "Myapp";

I did it for every different language supported by my app, but in apple watch companion app it is always shown the english CFBundleDisplayName.

Any idea on how properly localize apple watch companion app name?

thank you very much for helping

Comment: Where exactly you see not localized app name?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is a bug of the iOS9.
The reason is clear, There is no apps on AppStore that provides localized companion App Title.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug of iOS 9. Since that version (2015) watchOS companion apps are using their own **Info.plist** and **InfoPlist.strings** correspondingly to get the `CFBundleDisplayName`. So the simpliest way to solve this is to add localized **InfoPlist.strings** to watch app target (not extension). This can be done in **File inspector > Target Membership**.

For more details you can read [Apple tech note QA1892](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1892/_index.html).

And a very detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30065041/1746142) on SO that helped me to figure things out.

This isn't a common problem now, since watch app and extension targets got merged, but still may occur.